# What does $E(\rho)$ mean for $\rho$ being a probability mass function?

Tags: probability-theory, notation

Let $\rho$ be a probability mass function. Then what exactly is meant by $E(\rho)$? It is supposed to be the expected value of the probability mass function, but I never encountered such thing, and it isn't defined in the book I use. It appears in an example about a queuing model. As it seems, $E(\rho) \le 1$ is supposed to mean that on average, no more than customer comes in the given time interval. But what would be a precise definition for it?

Comment: $\int_0^1x\rho(x)dx$

Comment: Is there also a definition for it in the discrete case?

Comment: @user125261:  the integral has to extend over the whole support of $\rho(x)$

Comment: @RossMillikan very true, i was thinking of the range of $\rho$ by mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is the expected value of the random variable, which is the long term average of a large number of results.  If the probability mass function is continuous, it is $\int_{-\infty}^\infty x\rho(x)dx$.  If it is a discrete distribution it is $\sum_{i=-\infty}^\infty i\rho(i)$

Comment: Thanks! In my case, $\rho$ is defined on $\Bbb Z_+$. Can we rewrite the sum then?

Comment: You can delete any of the range where $\rho(i)=0$ because they will not contribute to the sum. If $rho(i)=0$ whenever $i \lt 0$ then you can make the lower limit of the sum $0$.